# How to get list of elements from XSOM parser

Tags: xml, xsd, xsom

With XSOM, how can I obtain information for elements from a sample schema? (see below)

I've been trying to use the iterateElementDecls() method but only can obtain the top element (note).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to navigate to complex type then you repeat the same method to get all elements inside the complex type definition.

Hope that helps
:)

Comment: A short example might be helpful.

Comment: After searching on a similar question I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320814/how-to-get-max-depth-of-a-xsd-using-xsom-dom-jaxb Hope it helps someone here in the future