# how to get max depth of a xsd using xsom\dom\jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsom

how to get max depth of a xsd using xsom.

For e.g: total number of elements under each complex types of the xsd?

Also if as complex types is there under that complex types the number of element + attributes under that......using dom\xsom\jaxb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="root" type="root">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Comment describing your root element
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="element_count" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="employee" type="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Addresses" type="addresses" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="addresses">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="address" type="address" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="line2" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was actually just looking for this. I could not find anything in the API, so found a way with recursion yesterday. I am simply pasting my recursive way to read to the deepest and add them into a Hashmap.

```
/*
 * Parses the xml schema string into a hashmap
 * note that hashmap has a form of a tree
 */
public HashMap<String, Object> getXmlElements(InputStream xml) {
    //---
    XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();
    //---
    try{
        parser.parse(xml);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        logger.fatal("Could not parse the inputstream: " + ex);
    }
    //---
    XSSchemaSet schemaSet = null;
    try {
        schemaSet = parser.getResult();
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        logger.fatal("Could not parse: " + ex);
    }
    //---
    HashMap<String, Object> hmReturned = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Iterator <XSElementDecl> itre = schemaSet.iterateElementDecls();
    //---
    while(itre.hasNext()) {
        XSElementDecl xse = (XSElementDecl) itre.next();
        hmReturned.put(xse.getName(), hm);
        XSComplexType xscomp = xse.getType().asComplexType();
        if (xscomp != null) {
            XSContentType xscont = xscomp.getContentType();
            XSParticle particle = xscont.asParticle();
            getElementsRecursively(hm,  particle);
        }
    } 
    //---
    return hmReturned;
}

/*
 * recursive helper method of getXmlElements
 * note that since we don't know the "deepness" of the
 * schema a recursive way of implementation was necessary
 */
private void getElementsRecursively(HashMap<String, Object> hm, XSParticle xsp) {
     if(xsp != null){
         XSTerm term = xsp.getTerm();
         if(term.isElementDecl()) {
             XSComplexType xscmp =  (term.asElementDecl()).getType().asComplexType();
             //---
             if (xscmp == null){
                 if(xsp.getMinOccurs() == 0)
                     hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), "|");
                 else
                     hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), "=");
             } else{
                 XSContentType xscont = xscmp.getContentType();
                 XSParticle particle = xscont.asParticle();
                 HashMap<String, Object> newHm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                 getElementsRecursively(newHm, particle);
                 hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), newHm);
             }
             //---
         } else if(term.isModelGroup()){
             XSModelGroup model = term.asModelGroup();
             XSParticle[] parr = model.getChildren();
             for(XSParticle partemp : parr ){
               getElementsRecursively(hm, partemp);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has a small bug: The line `HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();` from method `getXmlElements` should be inside the `while` block.

Comment: And `xsp.getMinOccurs() == 0` should be replaced with `xsp.getMinOccurs().intValue() == 0`, because the method returns a `BigInteger`.